# What is the scientist's name in "Far From Home" that knew about the other Earths?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

In *Spider-Man: Far From Home* Mysterio thanks a scientist for giving him a believable back story, what is this guy's name?

Answer (score 9):

#### Gutes Guterman

Beck mentions his name during the speech:

> **Quentin Beck:** To Guterman; the story you created of a soldier from another Earth named Quentin fighting space monsters in Europe is totally ridiculous, and apparently exactly the kind of thing people believe right now!
>
> <sub>*Spider-Man: Far From Home*</sub>

And whilst I'm pretty sure your title is written as it is to avoid spoilers I think it's worth being explicit here: There are no other Earths in *Far From Home*, it was all made up.

Comment: The Marvel Universe is based upon a multiverse. In Far from home Guterman Talks about one of these multiverse's earth 616 which is what the universe in avengers is called.

Comment: @scratchy151002 Whilst the multiverse is a thing in the MCU (only mentioned thus far but _Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness_ is likely to include it) there is zero indication anyone in Beck's team knew about it and a lot of evidence that it was all just made up. All the characters are from Earth-19999 (the MCU), the Earth-616 thing was just a reference to the comics main continuity.

Comment: Also I've seen Gutes Guterman referenced a lot but I can't find the source for his first name being Gutes...

Comment: Worth noting: while the Guterman came up with a story that Beck and his team thought was totally ridiculous about alternate realities, the (SHIELD?) people certainly didn't, and, probably more importantly, neither did Talos and Soren.

Comment: @KeithMorrison Well we don't see when they first discuss this so they could have found it ridiculous. I think you're inferring too much from a lack of evidence. Also I think it's clear that Talos and Soren were out of their depth.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot is it possible Gutes was used a nickname/shorthand for his last name? I mean it is possible as [Steve Stevens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Stevens) although a stage name and [Magnus Ver Magnusson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magn%C3%BAs_Ver_Magn%C3%BAsson)  and I'm sure many others have first and last names that basically the same ... but Gutes isn't exactly a common name

Comment: @Skooba not been used in the film that I can tell. I was thinking nickname but where I’ve seen people reference it, it was as if it’s a first name.